# Am I export gradle from eclipse right way?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

[image]

I want to use Android Studio, but I was working 2 Android Project with Eclipse.

So, I must take libraries and projects from Eclipse(workspace was 'D:\workspace4').

And I export gradle from Eclipse and in AndroidStudio, and go [File > Import Project... ] and select D:\workspace4\build.gradle.

But It seems that I import the Eclipse's workspace for one project.

I tried to export individual project from Eclipse, but I think It's failed.
Always root directory is workspace...

How can I export from My Eclipse's workspace correctly? Please help me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Migrating from eclipse Projects to android studio includes two options:

1) Exporting from Eclipse :-
 step 1:-Update your Eclipse ADT Plugin (you must have version 22.0 or higher).
    In Eclipse, select File > Export.

step 2:-In the window that appears, open Android and select Generate Gradle build files.

Step 3:-Select the project you want to export for Android Studio and click Finish.
Your selected project remains in the same location but now contains a build.gradle file and is ready for Android Studio.

2)Importing into android studio :-To import into Android Studio, select File > Import, and then select the directory containing your Eclipse ADT project. A wizard will open and guide you through the rest of the import process.
( When the project import has finished, it will open up a file called "import-summary.txt" which lists all the steps taken during import and suggestions for next steps. For example, it may note files that were not migrated,
it may note missing components in your SDK install, and so on.)